# Control correct values in a column

Tags: excel, modulus

I have an Excel file with a column of names that each name need to be repeated 70 times. The names can also be entered more than once. For example

```
Name
AAA
AAA
AAA
...(similarly repeated up to 70 times)
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
...(similarly repeated up to 70 times)
BBB
AAA
AAA
AAA
...(similarly repeated up to 70 times)
AAA
```

I want to check if might have been entered incorreclty, for example as follows

```
Name
AAA
ABB
AAA
...(similarly repeated up to 70 times)
AAA
```

At the moment I have a formula to control that names are not entered incorreclty as follows:

```
MOD(SUMIF(A:A,"AAA")+SUMIF(A:A,"BBB")+... , 70)
```

If the modulus 70 of the sum of all counts equal to zero, I know that all names have been entered correclty 70 times.

The problem is that every time new names are entered, I need to update the formula

Is there another formula that I could use that would count and sum the number of duplicated entries in a column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column (in sample B) with the formula:

```
B2 -> =IF(A2=A1;"";COUNTIF($A:$A;A2))
```

and autofomplete.
In a cell you make the check:

```
=MOD(SUM(B2:B9999);70)
```

Comment: Thanks user3514930. I was hoping to not to have to add a column but maybe there is no other option. Thanks